# Simple config fetching from Zookeeper

Tags: java, configuration, apache-zookeeper

I have to fetch some config from Zookeeper.
What I do now:

```
ZooKeeper zk = null;
try {
    zk = new ZooKeeper(zkConnect, 1000, null);
    byte[] fetched = zk.getData(CONFIG_ZNODE_PATH, false, null);
    zk.close();
    return deserializeProps(fetched);
} finally {
    if (zk != null) {
        zk.close();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure whether I'm doing this simple thing in a right way because in the [doc](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/master/src/java/main/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.java) it's stated:

> Session establishment is asynchronous. This constructor will initiate connection to the server and return immediately - potentially (usually) before the session is fully established.

Does it mean that the code is invalid and I cannot call `getData` simply after constructor call?

By the way, no error appears when running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens here is, zookeeper establishes the connection to the zookeeper ensemble in background. Therefore by the time you call your method to fetch configuration, the connection and session have been correctly established.

This will work fine as long as you have a perfect network where the zookeeper client is always able to find the zookeeper server. But, if your client become unable to find the zookeeper server for some time, this will throw an exception I guess and your operation will fail.

To address that, either you have to wait till the zookeeper client gets connected as follows,

```
private ZooKeeper zk;
final CountDownLatch connectionLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void yourMethod() {

    zk = new ZooKeeper(zkConnect, 2000, new Watcher() {

        public void process(WatchedEvent we) {
            if (we.getState() == KeeperState.SyncConnected) {
                connectionLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    });

    connectionLatch.await();

    // Now we have connected to zookeeper.
    // Now, we can fetch configuration safely.
    byte[] fetched = zk.getData(CONFIG_ZNODE_PATH, false, null);
    return deserializeProps(fetched);
}
```

Remember that your way is not wrong, its just unsafe. In your case, it worked well. If the network delay is large, this may not work as you expect. What I suggested was a safer way.

I used the codes given in [this blog post](http://java.globinch.com/enterprise-services/zookeeper/apache-zookeeper-explained-tutorial-cases-zookeeper-java-api-examples/#ZooKeeper-API-Java-Examples-Connection) to explain my suggestion. You can refer that too to get a better understanding.

Comment: I thought of similar implementation. Probably going to update my code, thanks.